# How to control the data shown on Excel chart axis?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I want to create a bar chart of the probabilities of two dice in Excel. This would appear to require the following data:

[image]

However, selecting that range and requesting a bar char results in both sets of data being plotted on the chart:

[image]

If I just select the result then I get the shape of graph I'm after:

[image]

But the axis is wrong - along the bottom, I need the numbers 2-12 rather than 1-11.

Controlling the axis of a graph in Excel seems unnecessarily complicated, and I presume there must be an easier way to do this - it's my ignorance that's stopping me. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's required to adjust the Axis Labels:

[image: Axis Labels]

Change your Axis Labels to match the Result column:

[image]